# babeljs is not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I've installed Babeljs by using

> sudo npm install -global babel-cli

my test ES6 file contain

> let name = 'Teh';
>
> console.log(name);

and then , i try to compiled ES6 by using (ref. hxxps://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/)

> babel test.js

---

The output of babel has not been complied.

[Please see the image , "let" should be converted to "var"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TEAe.png)

Did i do something wrong? Please help me to solve this problem , i'm a new in ES6.

Thank you.

**Sorry for my bad English.

-- Update

[Try to specified the output file : babel test.js --out-file test-compiled.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dmW1.png)

Comment: I don't think it overrides the content of the original file whie converting. Try specifying an output file: `babel test.js --out-file test-compiled.js`

Comment: i've try to specified , got the same output ==> http://i.stack.imgur.com/7dmW1.png

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: sorry about that. if i've fould the answer , i'll not ask new question.